# CSS positioning: Relative influences stacking order without z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've encountered something weird with CSS that I can't find an explanation for.

Using `position: absolute`, a `div` *a* is pulled above another `div` *b*. When `div` *b* (sitting below *a*) has a child with `position: relative`, that element appears above *a*.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent')

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
 parent.classList.toggle('toggle-class')
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.child-a {
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.child-b {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle-class .child-b span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-a">
    child a
  </div>
  <div class="child-b">
    <span>child b' child</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button>
toggle
</button>
```

My first reaction was to read up on stacking contexts, but since no `z-index` is at play, this has probably something to do with positioning. Still, I don't understand how this is possible – why does the element appear above when `position: relative` is applied?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of stacking context. Note that it's not just `z-index` values that form a stacking context. Positioned elements do as well. So `.parent` creates a stacking context because it is positioned `relative`. When toggled, the `.child-b` span is then positioned relative to `.parent`.

See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am a bit confused because the docs say 'Element with a position value "absolute" or "relative" *and z-index value other than "auto"*.' (emphasis mine). Since I have only defined `position` as `relative`, `z-index` should be at its initial value, which is `auto`. Why does a new stacking still context form?

Answer (score 1):

When stacking without `z-index` the  elements are stacked in the following order (from bottom to top):

> 1. The background and borders of the root element
> 2. Descendant non-positioned blocks, in order of appearance in the HTML
> 3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance in the HTML

Source [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

So what happens in your case is that the Descendant (child), when toggled turns into a positioned element  and so its parent (because the grandparent (`.parent`)  is a positioned element).

Following the rule #3 the latter element to appear in HTML will show up, therefore this behavior